# Want to allocate loops to specific table headers

Tags: javascript, html, loops

This is the html part:

```
</head>
<body>
<div class = "container">

    <h1>Your custom BMI table </h1>
    <p>This table shows your current height and weight, plus or minus up to ten pounds, 
    and the corresponding BMI calculations.  It also indicates if a BMI is a categorized as 
    underweight, healthy, overweight, or obese.</p>
    <p>Your current weight is indicated in bold text.</p>
    <p></p>
    <table id="output" class="table-bordered">
        <tr>
            <th id = "table-height">Height (inches)</th>
            <th id = "table-weight">Weight (lbs)</th>
            <th id = "table-bmi">BMI</th>
            <th id = "table-category">Category</th>
        </tr>
    </table>
</div>
```

I want the weight to go under the weight header in cells, but i cant figure out whats going on

```
var i = 0;
for (var i = weight - 10; i <= weight + 10; i++) {
    console.log(i);     
    var tableWeight = document.getElementById('th');
    $(tableWeight).find('tbody').append( "<tr><td>" + i + "</td></tr>" );
}
```

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

As I assume you are trying to create a table with 4 headings Height, Weight, BMI, Category
And you are getting a weight and rendering weights from w-10 to w+10. 
If I assume correctly, your problem is weight is getting rendered under the Heights and not Weights.

Solution is just simple, Add a  before the actual weight, because you are filling values for height and not filling values for the rest of the columns

I've updated your script's append call as below

```
$(tableWeight).find('tbody').append( "<tr><td></td><td>" + i + "</td></tr>" );
```

check out this fiddle here: https://jsfiddle.net/v7g4sk9q/6/